# Unable to plot a scatter plot in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, statistics, random-number-generator

I have taken integers from 1 to 100 as my total population set. Now I generated 5 random numbers (using **=randbetween()** command) and called it my sample 1. Similarly, I created 200 such samples. Now I changed the number of data points in my sample and increased it to 10 in each sample and again created 200 new samples with sample size = 10. This thing I again did for sample size = 20. Now my problem is this - I have to plot them in such a manner that on my X-axis, I have Sample size = 5, sample size = 10, sample size = 20 as my 3 points and all the sample points corresponding to each sample size on the Y-axis (hence making 3 different clustered scatter plot in shape of straight line). But I am unable to do so. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can you demonstrate your problem? It's a lot of work to sort through your thoughts. I'm sure you can do it with a pencil to illistrate. Sounds like you have want 3 Scatter Plots; one for each sample size 5,10,20. You really want a dot (center of mass) in each population sample and then you want a "linear extrapolation" running through each populations's center. Is that right?

Comment: I want one scatter plot. And I want all the data points in my graph. It will look like 3 vertically linear dots like structure.

Comment: That's the result you desire. What your data is, is 3 scatter plots yes?

Comment: You really need to set your data up as data in a chart and display what you have so far. You are leaving it up to the reader to guess what you've actually done. Statistics is planning and it takes time, running Excel is quite different. You should present your data to maximize the help to minimized the WORK effort you are leaving up to us volunteers.

Comment: It sounds like you generated1,000 random values and said each group of 5 is a sample.  Then you generated 2,000 random points and said each group of 10 is a sample.  Then 4,000 random points and said each group of 20 is a sample.  You aren't doing anything with the sample groupings, just plotting 1,000, 2,000, and 4,000 points at X values corresponding to what you said the sample sizes were.  The same process generated all 7,000 points, so you will just have different sized collections of similar random points aligned at three locations.  (cont'd)

Comment: A scatter plot requires every point to have an X and Y value.  The X value is what you say the sample size was and the Y value is the random number you generated.  So in column A, fill in the number 5 in A1 and copy it down 1,000 rows.  The first 1,000 random numbers will go in B1:B1000.  Similarly, enter 10 in A1001 and copy it down through A3000.  The 2,000 random numbers for sample size 10 go in B1001:B3000.  Similar for sample size 20.  The value 20 will end at A7000 and the last random number from sample size 20 will be in B7000.  Now select A1:B7000 and plot it as a scatter chart.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3047128?tstart=0

Comment: One additional point.  Take your 4,000 values from sample size 20.  It doesn't make any difference whether you say that represents 200 samples of 20, or 100 samples of 40, or 1 sample of 4,000.  It's the same 4,000 points.  So you can call it any sample size you want, and those 4,000 points will get placed at whatever location you say.

Comment: @ ejbytes,fixer1234 - Thanks, it worked perfectly. Although as fixer1234 pointed , now I'm wondering what is the use of grouping the dataset?

Comment: Seems like a project or assignment? I think the idea is to realized that the more data points you have the more obvious the linear extrapolation (correlation) looks. The more points you have the more obvious it becomes. It also leads you to believe that a Sample CAN be the same as a Population. Try making three graphs, one for each set instead of just one, to see my point.